# How to copy desired log file content when logs are frequently being rotated in Linux

Tags: linux, grep, backup, cp, logrotate

Suppose some logs is being rotated by size 50MB each . I did `grep` some string and my string is present in a log file, `log_3` and I want to copy the content of `log_3` before it gets rotated(renamed) to `log_4`.

Please suggest how to take backup of the content of log_3 before it is rotated. I just need the content of log_3. I don't want like I copied log_3 (by cp -p log_3 log_3_backup) but by that time logs got rotated and now log_3_backup contains content of log_2. Is there any way we can do to avoid this. Working on an automation project I need a solution to this. Thank you very much for your suggestions in advance. You May share python or shell script.

Comment: It seems to me that grep && cp is a good solution; why not?

Comment: is that rotated log is readable? or will it be zipped?

Comment: Make a hard link. `ln log_3 log_safe`. The linked file will remain even if log_3 gets removed or renamed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use grep to find the lines you are looking for and append them to your a new log file of only useful information.

ie. grep someString *.log >> errors.txt

Answer (score 0):

If the rotated log is readable, you can simply `cat` all files and `grep` desire pattern.

Example:

```
cat /path/to/backup/* log_3 | grep <pattern>
```